# How to recover session buddy extension data chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Cleared my cache as part of pc maintenance /optimization and now my sessions from session buddy are gone. Is there any way to recover them?

If not is there a way to recover session data from google history?  v

I don't have a previous version option on my chrome/user data

I do have sync onto my google account but I cannot find the extension data.

Comment: Clearing cache is not any part of maintenance/optimisation, it is an interweb meme, fake news. Cache is like soap… it is self-cleaning. Recover from your backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin  where is the backup?  I'll keep that in mind, but hp support insists on clearing cache

Comment: Your backup is wherever you save your backups. No support of any kind should be advocating cache clearing in this day & age. It's a prehistoric misconception.

Comment: dang I was hoping windows/chrome kept a backup somewhere